# C : How to send an int type variable to an array of char?

Tags: c, casting

I am trying to write an integer variable, named **value**, in an array of char buffer, named **buf_wr**.
This is the function where I am facing the problem :

```
void receiveData(int n, siginfo_t *info, void *unused) 
{
    int nw;
    int fd;
    char buf_wr[10];
    int value;

    printf(" \nreceived value %i\n", info->si_int);
    value = (info->si_int);
    printf("value = %i\n", value);
    sprintf(buf_wr, "%i", value);
    printf("buf_wr contains : %i\n", buf_wr);
    nw = write(fd,buf_wr,strlen(buf_wr));
    if (nw < 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to write the message to the device.");
    }
}
```

When I execute the entire code, it shows me :

```
received value 260
value = 260
buf_wr contains : 135264
```

**buf_wr** does not contain the value I want to get into it which is **260**.

How can I fix the problem ? Thank you.

Comment: Compilers warn about stuff like `printf("%i", (char*)x)` mismatches. A good starting point would be to read the warnings.

Comment: @PSkocik No, I am using cross compiler that did not show me any warning for that problem!

Comment: [tag:c] uses null terminated strings so `char buf_wr[10];` is not enough (assuming 32 bit integers) to store the worst case `−2147483647`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("buf_wr contains : %i\n", buf_wr);
```

You should be using `%s` to print `string`.

```
printf("buf_wr contains : %s\n", buf_wr);
```

Comment: `char buf_wr[10]` ----> `char buf_wr[12]` at least and use `snprintf` to check string bounds properly